# Datetimepicker not working with different formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Hi I was trying to make a filter for reservations where people would be able to filter in between what dates they want to register. I used datetime picker (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) but the form to pickers are not working(is not letting me to chose a date from). I am using d.m.Y format and that seems to be the problem as it is working with Y/d/m but we cannot use this format. Here is my code:

```
function addPicker() {
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('cs');
$( "#from" ).datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d.m.Y',
    value:  '+1970/01/02', //today
    scrollMonth : false,
    scrollInput : false,
    minDate: '+1970/01/02',
    onShow:function( ct ){
        this.setOptions({
            maxDate:$('#to').val()?jQuery('#to').val():false
        })
    }
});
$( "#to" ).datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d.m.Y',
    value:  '+1970/01/08', //a week from today
    scrollMonth : false,
    scrollInput : false,
    onShow:function( ct ){
        this.setOptions({
            minDate:jQuery('#from').val()?jQuery('#from').val():false
        })
    }

});
}
$(document).ready(function () {
addPicker();
});
```

and html:

```
<input type="text" name="from" id="from">
<input type="text" name="to" id="to">
```

Please if you have any hints let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt your issues are related to the format string since there are working examples on [the plugin page you linked to](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) using the exact same format as you.

Comment: you want a date `from` could be and date or must be a future date? also the date `to` what behavior you are trying to have?

Comment: "from" must be tomorrow as customers wont be able to book for the current date. the limit must be "to" date as from 3.4 to 1.4 would not make any sense.

Comment: @AndréDion someone made a working snipplet where you can see where the problem is. When we changed the format to Y/d/m it started to work as inteded .. Just try yourself.  I would rather hear a help

Comment: You can either provide a direct example that exhibits the behaviour you're describing or you can watch this question get downvoted, ignored or closed. If what you say is true, then file a bug against the plugin. Conjecture isn't helpful for anyone.

Comment: @AndréDion ok I have solved this with temporary solution (via my answer) you can even see the working example there. I am sorry I had no idea how to put working script straight into this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems like authors did not think about returning different formats to maxDate so I have created a small script to transfer my date to US format. Just gonna leave it here so it helps someone else.

```
function convertDate(czechDate){
   var parsed = czechDate.split(".");
   return parsed[2]+"/"+parsed[1]+"/"+parsed[0];
}
```

and changed the original code.

```js
function addPicker() {
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale('cs');

  $("#from").datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'd.m.Y',
    value: '+1970/01/02', //today
    scrollMonth: false,
    scrollInput: false,
    minDate: '+1970/01/02',
    onShow: function(ct) {
      this.setOptions({

        maxDate: $('#to').val() ? convertDate(jQuery('#to').val()) : false
      })
    }
  });
  $("#to").datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'd.m.Y',
    value: '+1970/01/08', //a week from today
    scrollMonth: false,
    scrollInput: false,
    onShow: function(ct) {
      this.setOptions({
        minDate: jQuery('#from').val() ? convertDate(jQuery('#from').val()) : false
      })
    }

  });
}

function convertDate(czechDate) {
  var parsed = czechDate.split(".");
  return parsed[2] + "/" + parsed[1] + "/" + parsed[0];
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  addPicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" name="from" id="from">
<input type="text" name="to" id="to">
```